# InvalidOperationException when saving child object with collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class Foo, with a property of type ISet. The Bar class in turn has a Foo property and an ISet of MiniBars. Using NHibernate I wish to persist an instance of Foo, and after that, but still within the same NHibernate transaction, add an instance of Bar to the Bars property of the Foo object and the Foo object to the Foo property of the Bar object and then see that also the Bar object is persisted when I commit the transaction.

However, I get an Excepetion from somewhere inside NHibernate: "System.InvalidOperationException : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

I've come to the conclusion that this has something to do with the ISet of MiniBars. In the default constructor of Bar this set is set using

```
MiniBars = new HashedSet<MiniBar>();
```

If I remove this line of code, or remove the mapping of the MiniBars property from Bar.hbm.xml, everything works as supposed.

The not working code:

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Foo.Id = 1;
  session.Save(foo);

  Bar bar = new Bar
  {
    Foo = foo; // The setter for Foo also adds Bar to the set Foo.Bars
  }

  tx.Commit(); // I wish this to save both foo and bar
}
```

The stack trace of the thrown exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeCollectionElements(Object child, CollectionType collectionType, CascadeStyle style, IType elemType, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Cascade.cs: line 231
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeCollection(Object child, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, CollectionType type) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Cascade.cs: line 201
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeAssociation(Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Cascade.cs: line 185
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeProperty(Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Cascade.cs: line 148
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Cascade.cs: line 126
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.CascadeOnFlush(IEventSource session, IEntityPersister persister, Object key, Object anything) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs: line 207
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs: line 195
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs: line 48
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEventListener.cs: line 18
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs: line 1472
at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs: line 187
at Company.Product.Test.DatabaseDependentFixtureBase.FillDatabase() in DatabaseDependentFixtureBase.cs: line 121
at Company.Product.Test.DatabaseDependentFixtureExample.Temp() in DatabaseDependentFixture.cs: line 40
```

The stack trace points out this function from NHibernate.Engine.Cascade:

```
    private void CascadeCollectionElements(object child, CollectionType collectionType, CascadeStyle style, IType elemType, object anything, bool isCascadeDeleteEnabled)
    {
        // we can't cascade to non-embedded elements
        bool embeddedElements = eventSource.EntityMode != EntityMode.Xml
                                || ((EntityType) collectionType.GetElementType(eventSource.Factory)).IsEmbeddedInXML;

        bool reallyDoCascade = style.ReallyDoCascade(action) && embeddedElements
                               && child != CollectionType.UnfetchedCollection;

        if (reallyDoCascade)
        {
            log.Info("cascade " + action + " for collection: " + collectionType.Role);

            foreach (object o in action.GetCascadableChildrenIterator(eventSource, collectionType, child))
                CascadeProperty(o, elemType, style, anything, isCascadeDeleteEnabled);

            log.Info("done cascade " + action + " for collection: " + collectionType.Role);
        }

        var childAsPersColl = child as IPersistentCollection;
        bool deleteOrphans = style.HasOrphanDelete && action.DeleteOrphans && elemType.IsEntityType
                             && childAsPersColl != null; //a newly instantiated collection can't have orphans

        if (deleteOrphans)
        {
            // handle orphaned entities!!
            log.Info("deleting orphans for collection: " + collectionType.Role);

            // we can do the cast since orphan-delete does not apply to:
            // 1. newly instantiated collections
            // 2. arrays (we can't track orphans for detached arrays)
            string entityName = collectionType.GetAssociatedEntityName(eventSource.Factory);
            DeleteOrphans(entityName, childAsPersColl);

            log.Info("done deleting orphans for collection: " + collectionType.Role);
        }
    }
```

There is a foreach loop in this function, but I can't see that the collection is altered within the loop. I've followed the method calls as long as I can, but since I have not looked into the NHibernate source code before, it's quite overwhelming.

I guess it *could* be a bug in NHibernate, but I think it's more likely that I'm doing something wrong when using NHibernate. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Any solution to this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I left the project with this problem just a short while after I wrote the question, so I'm afraid I don't remember how we worked around this problem, or even if we did so.

Answer (score 2):

The error you described occurs when you are in the process of enumerating over a collection and proceed to attempt to modify the collection while doing so. Here is an example of this:

```
List<string> someCollection = new List<string>();

someCollection.Add("Hello");
someCollection.Add("World");
someCollection.Add("Hello");
someCollection.Add("World");

// Enumerate the collection
foreach (string item in someCollection)
{
    // If the item is "World", remove it from the collection
    if ("World".Equals(item))
    {
        someCollection.Remove(item); // This will throw an InvalidOperationException.
    }
}
```

In the example above, the exception is thrown when we try to remove an item from the collection we are in the process of enumerating. This is an invalid operation. To overcome this, you need to alter the way the collection is modified. Examples of alternate approaches would be to enumerate a copy of the collection (i.e. `foreach (var item in someCollection.ToArray())`); or to delay the collection modification until after you have finished enumerating.

I would suggest looking at the source of the exception (which I'm going to assume points to some collection enumeration) and then look around that point for some modification of that collection.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should have written that the exception is thrown from NHibernate on `tx.Commit()`. I do not enumerate any collections in my own code.

Comment: You may not be doing the enumeration yourself, it is still possible that you may be causing a collection modification during some internal enumeration of the same collection. Have a look at the stack trace in the exception and see *exactly* what piece of code is thrown the exception. You can then use [.NET Reflector](http://bit.ly/wnTYIm) to have a look at the NHibernate code (if that is throwing it) to see the disassembled view of the code in question. That may help lead to uncovering the cause.